# hidden routines linked in c program

Tags: c, winapi, compiler-construction, linker

Hullo,
When one disasembly some win32 exe prog compiled by c compiler it
shows that some compilers links some 'hidden' routines in it -
i think even if c program is an empty one and has a 5 bytes or so.

I understand that such 5 bytes is enveloped in PE .exe format but
why to put some routines - it seem not necessary for me and even 
somewhat annoys me. What is that? Can it be omitted? As i understand
c program (not speaking about c++ right now which i know has some 
initial routines) should not need such complementary hidden functions..

Much tnx for answer, maybe even some extended info link, cause this
topic interests me much

//edit

ok here it is some disasembly Ive done way back then
(digital mars and old borland commandline (i have tested also)
both make much more code, (and Im specialli interested in bcc32) 
but they do not include readable names/symbols in such dissassembly 
so i will not post them here

thesse are somewhat readable - but i am not experienced in understending
what it is ;-)

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42887985/prog_devcpp.htm

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42887985/prog_lcc.htm

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42887985/prog_mingw.htm

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42887985/prog_pelles.htm

some explanatory comments whats that heere? 
(I am afraid maybe there is some c++ sh*t here, I am
interested in pure c addons not c++ though,
but too tired now to assure that it was compiled in c
mode, extension of compiled empty-main prog was c
so I was thinking it will be output in c not c++)

tnx for longer explanations what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your win32 exe file is a dynamically linked object file,  it will contain the necessary data needed by the dynamic linker to do its job, such as names of libraries to link to, and symbols that need resolving.

Even a program with an empty `main()` will link with the c-runtime and kernel32.dll libraries (and probably others? - a while since I last did Win32 dev).

You should also be aware that `main()` is only the entry point of *your* program - quite a bit has already gone on before this point such as retrieving and tokening the command-line, setting up the locale, creating `stderr`, `stdin`, and `stdout` and setting up the other mechanism required by the c-runtime library such a `at_exit()`.  Similarly, when your `main()` returns, the runtime does some clean-up - and at the very least needs to call the kernel to tell it that you're done.

As to whether it's necessary?  Yes, unless you fancy writing your own program prologue and epilogue each time.  There are probably are ways of writing minimal, statically linked applications if you're sufficiently masochistic.

As for storage overhead, why are you getting so worked up? It's not enough to worry about.

Comment: Could You explain, what is such c-runtime ? I do not understand what it is, if c prog needs 'runtime' it is in the system, not in the form of linked-in hidden routines. Six or Eight things things you mention (processing commandline, setting up locale...) are VERY interesting, but need it be done through hidden functions? What it is - some linked-in wrappers on winapi routines ?? (If so maybe it would explain the thing) TnX Much

Comment: A while ago I read a page about creating the smallest exe file. I quickly searched for it and found this one (not exactly the same I saw before, but similar): http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/

Comment: @rpsml Ive readed it half or a year ago, This is extremally good article, yes. But it shows that here no hidden routines are needed ro run code... So it do not explain what routines linkers link in :/ :O :[

Comment: By c-runtime I mean the companion library that goes along with a compiler.  It includes the implementations of C standard library functions, but also support functions where the compiler (and linker) generate calls to functions rather than code when compiling and linking.  

On systems with *NIX heritage, this is usually all contained in libc and on Windows systems in Kernel32.dll

In both cases, there are wrappers to system calls - for instance for IO, thread management, memory management and so on.

Comment: @grungefightr would you care to provide a dump of what they actually are?    It's a safe bet that almost everybody writing software in C will want standard library functions - and I'd tend to be very suspicious of anything that wasn't (hello malware!)

Comment: If they are wrappers - for example malloc is a wrapper on VirtualAlloc or something, arent they are just a normal linked routines (though wrappers) ?  Could not understand what is such runtime - it confuses things more. If I would wrote winapi progs in pure assembly (produce win exe in assembly) Will I meet some need of writing some routines equal to the hidden mentioned? The best would be to konow exactly what it is - As to question "would you care to provide dump" I do not understand it (weak english) You want me to paste some disassembly?

Comment: Yes. post a disassembly of the extra stuff. 

The implementation of `malloc()` and `free()` are considerably more than a wrapper to a sys-call - but all of these - and sys-call wrapper functions will all be dynamically linked.

Answer (score 1):

There are several initialization functions that load whenever you run a program on Windows.  These functions, among other things, call the main() function that you write - which is why you need either a main() or WinMain() function for your program to run.  I'm not aware of other included functions though.  Do you have some disassembly to show?

Comment: I ve tested it with a three or four small old compilers and noticed that 'amount' of such routines differ, some put less some much more. Disasembly shows that they exist but got no symbols and no info what it is

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much detail to go on but I think most of what you're seeing is probably the routines of the specific C runtime library that your compiler works with.

For instance there will be code enabling it to run from the entry point 'main' which portable executable format understands to call the main(char ** args) that you wrote in your C program.

Comment: What is such c-runtime exactly. What is such mysterious code which enables my main to run? Where I could find Info on such strange thing? I am seeking for much more info on this things / hidden routines :(